# Sufficient condition for a matrix to have full rank almost surely

Tags: linear-algebra, probability-theory

Merry x-mas! So, I have a continuous map $f : X\to\mathbb R^N$ on a topological space $X$, a Borel probability measure $\mu$ on $X$, and $m\ge N$ independent samples $x_1,\ldots,x_m$ from the distribution $\mu$. What I would like to have is a sufficient condition for the matrix
$$
F = [f(x_1),\ldots,f(x_m)]\,\in\mathbb R^{N\times m}
$$
to have full (row) rank $N$ almost surely. However, I can only prove a necessary condition, namely

> For all $\lambda\in\mathbb R^N\backslash\{0\}$ we have $\mu(\{x\,|\,\lambda^\top f(x)=0\}) = 0$.

In particular, the zero set of each $f_i$ has zero measure.

In order to see that this is necessary, let $F$ have full rank almost surely, i.e.,
$$
\mu^m(\{(x_1,\ldots,x_m)\,|\,\exists\lambda\in\mathbb R^N\backslash\{0\} : \lambda^\top f(x_k)=0\,\forall k=1,\ldots,m\}) = 0,
$$
and suppose that there exists $\lambda_0\in\mathbb R^N\backslash\{0\}$ such that $\mu(\{x\,|\,\lambda_0^\top f(x)=0\}) > 0$. Let $Z := \{x\,|\,\lambda_0^\top f(x)=0\}$. Then
\begin{align*}
0
&= \mu^m(\{(x_1,\ldots,x_m)\,|\,\exists\lambda\in\mathbb R^N\backslash\{0\} : \lambda^\top f(x_k)=0\,\forall k=1,\ldots,m\})\\
&\ge \mu^m(\{(x_1,\ldots,x_m)\,|\,\lambda_0^\top f(x_k)=0\,\forall k=1,\ldots,m\})\\
&= \mu^m(\{(x_1,\ldots,x_m)\,|\,x_k\in Z\,\forall k=1,\ldots,m\})\\
&= \mu^m(Z^m) = [\mu(Z)]^m > 0,
\end{align*}
a contradiction.

My question:

> Is this condition also sufficient for $F$ to be full rank almost surely? And, if not, do you know of a sufficient condition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is sufficient.

Suppose your condition is satisfied. $f(x_1)$ is a.s. nonzero, since otherwise (for any $\lambda \ne 0$) it would have nonzero probability of being in the hyperplane $\{y: \lambda^T y = 0\}$.  Conditional on $x_1$, $f(x_2)$ is a.s. not in the span of $f(x_1)$, otherwise (for any nonzero $\lambda$ orthogonal to $f(x_1)$) it would have nonzero probability of being in $\{y: \lambda^T y = 0\}$.  Continuing in this manner, for all $1 \le k \le N$,
$f(x_k)$ is a.s. not in the span of $f(x_1), \ldots, f(x_{k-1})$.  Thus
a.s. $f(x_1), \ldots, f(x_N)$ are linearly independent, which means
your matrix has full rank.